# Quero agrupar dados do banco(firebird) para enviar emails

Tags: mysql, firebird

Bom, eu estou selecionando os dados para o envio do e-mail nesse SELECT:

```
SELECT V.id_venda_cab,
V.id_cliente,
V.Total, 
C.nome,
i.id_produto, 
p.descricao,
C.email
FROM VENDA_CAB V INNER JOIN CLIENTE C ON C.ID_CLIENTE = V.ID_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN venda_item i ON i.id_venda_cab = v.id_venda_cab
inner join produto p on p.id_produto = i.id_produto
WHERE V.faturado = 'N'
ORDER BY V.ID_VENDA_CAB
```

E Ele retorna:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu quero agrupar os dados de um mesmo id_venda, onde os clientes são iguais, mas os produtos são outros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui o Resultado desejado usando:

```
select CODIGO,
LIST(DESCRICAO,',') as DESCRICRAO,
LIST(distinct(NOME)) as Nome,
LIST(distinct(EMAIL)) as Email,
List(distinct(Tot)) as Total FROM(SELECT V.id_venda_cab AS CODIGO,
V.Total AS TOT,
C.nome AS NOME,
p.descricao AS DESCRICAO,
C.email AS EMAIL
FROM VENDA_CAB V INNER JOIN CLIENTE C ON C.ID_CLIENTE = V.ID_CLIENTE
INNER JOIN venda_item i ON i.id_venda_cab = v.id_venda_cab
inner join produto p on p.id_produto = i.id_produto
WHERE V.faturado = 'N'
ORDER BY V.id_venda_cab)
GROUP BY CODIGO
```

usei o list() e o distinct() para distinguir dados repetidos.